# Still get 'curl/curl.h: No such file or directory' in spite of all looks proper

Tags: c, curl, mingw

I installed on windows `curl 7.28.0` from `curl-7.28.1-devel-mingw32.zip` through `minGW` console to default directory like:

```
./config && make && make install
```

All needed headers (aka `curl.h, types.h ...`) I see in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\include\curl`

`libcurl.pc` placed  in  `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib\pkgconfig\`

`libcurl.a`, `libcurl.dll.a` and `libcurl.la` placed in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib`.

My `download_file.c` file includes are:

```
...
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
...
```

I try to compile the `C` code with followed command through `gcc`:

```
$ gcc -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/ 
      -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/curl
      -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/pkgconfig
           -o download_file download_file.c -llibcurl -lcurl
```

with absolute path get the same error:

```
gcc -I/include/
    -I/local/include/curl
    -I/local/lib/pkgconfig
        -o download_file download_file.c -llibcurl -lcurl
```

But I still get an error:

```
download_file.c:21:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

row 21 is `#include <curl/curl.h>`

What I did wrong? Please help.

Comment: Wait, you compile *in* msys, but give Win32 paths?

Comment: `msys/1.0` my default folder under minGW. I installed and compiled a lot of things there like openssl, iLBC, msx264 and other stuff

Comment: please see my answer. I think the problem are the include paths you give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `curl/` directory in the source code, but *also* in the option.

It seems the option should point out the higher-level directory in which `curl/` is, so it should be something like:

```
-I/local/include/
```

Comment: Good catch, didn't realize that part of the problem. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is likely that you give your include paths on the command line in the Win32 path format. This is not the same as the one used by msys (or ultimately Cygwin).

Try these:

```
$ gcc -I/include/ 
      -I/local/include/curl
      -I/local/lib/pkgconfig
      ...
```

Hope I got the absolut paths right, but you can check in your msys shell.

What ticked me off was that you use `./config`, which wouldn't work from the Command Prompt, but works from the msys shell. So you need to give paths that all the programs in MinGW understand.

Basically, most programs in MinGW only have the concept of a single file system root, like on any unixoid system, while Win32 has multiple (the drive letters). Since the MinGW programs are linked accordingly, you need to give paths that they understand.

Comment: Thank you for response, see my fix, I get the same error :(. BTW: when I tried to compile project with openssl I ran: `gcc -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/ -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/openssl/  -LC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/ssl/lib/  -o openssl_aes openssl_aes.c -lcrypto -lgdi32` and it works

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to @0xC0000022L and @unwind.  By your help I fixed my problem.

**0xC0000022L** you are right about absolute path

**unwind** you are right about `-I/local/include/` instead `-I/local/include/curl`

I found other problem: `-L/local/lib` instead `-I/local/lib`.

So this is a working command:

```
gcc -I/include/
    -I/local/include
    -L/local/lib
         -o download_file download_file.c  -llibcurl -lcurl
```